# Optimize JavaScript time complexity (loop+IndexOf) for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, time-complexity

For Sentiment Analysis, I am using the below function to count the number of words in a text that exist in the array of positive words (p_Words) and the number of words that exist in the (n_Words). Is there a way to perform the same functionality with less time complexity?

I believe the below is O(N*M) as the indexOf is O(N) and I loop over the full string O(M).

```
var content = 'I am happy, this is such a beautiful morning';
var pCount = 0;
var nCount = 0;
var sCount = 0;
var words = content.split(" ");
var size = words.length;

for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if (s_Words.indexOf(words[j]) > -1) {
        sCount++;
    } else {
        if (p_Words.indexOf(words[j]) > -1) {
            pCount++;
        }
        if (n_Words.indexOf(words[j]) > -1) {
            nCount++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(pCount);
console.log(nCount);
console.log(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the each array into a regular expression, and count the results of the match:

```js
var s_Words = ['I', 'is', 'am', 'this', 'a'];
var p_Words = ['happy', 'beautiful', 'morning'];
var n_Words = ['such'];

var content = 'I am happy, this is such a beautiful morning';

function count(arr, str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') +')\\b', 'ig');

  return (str.match(pattern) || []).length;
}

console.log('s_Words: ', count(s_Words, content));
console.log('p_Words: ', count(p_Words, content));
console.log('n_Words: ', count(n_Words, content));
```

Another option is to create a dictionary of words with their type, and then you can iterate the string in O(n) to get the counts:

```js
var x_words = {
  s: ['I', 'is', 'am', 'this', 'a'],
  p: ['happy', 'beautiful', 'morning'],
  n: ['such']
};

var dict = Object.keys(x_words).reduce(function(r, key) {
  x_words[key].forEach(function(w) {
    r[w] = key;
  });
  
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

var content = 'I am happy, this is such a beautiful morning';
var words = content.match(/\w+/g);

var counts = words.reduce(function(r, w) {
  var key = dict[w];
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
  
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: If the word exists in the stopping words we should stop and not check for the word in the positive or negative datasets

Comment: Can you explain what this regular expression does (each part)? var pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') +')\\b', 'ig');

Comment: You should add more data about your problem - the s_Words, n_Words, p_Words arrays, what are you trying to achieve, etc...

Comment: The `var pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') +')\\b', 'ig');` will produce this pattern `/\b(happy|beautiful|morning)\b/` - match any of the words that are surrounded by a word boundary - ie not a part of another word.